# How to avoid the use of LiveData on the view model for a single event?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-mvvm

According the next article: https://proandroiddev.com/when-not-to-use-livedata-6a1245b054a6

We should skip the use of live data and an observer if we dont want to observer those changes :

In my case I have the next code, but If I don't add a LiveData event, I can't test it, becase the code is not on the viewModel, but is too much to create an observable with liveData only to execute one action that not require to be observed, which options there is to resolve that and be able to test the code on the view model ?

```
        buttonContainer.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
            val uri: Uri = Uri.fromParts(SCHEME, activity?.packageName, null)
            intent.data = uri
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

Comment: The code you have added has nothing to do with `LiveData` . Add a [mcve] and explain the problem .

Comment: I don't use liveData because, that is the point of my question. How to use that code, without use LiveData, and an observer in the view, is too much to add an observable for an event that don't require to be observer, only executed, and be testable on the viewModel

Comment: There is not need of an observer for this code . `LiveData` only comes handy when you listening for changes in data or State . The code you have provided is just an `Intent` there is no need of a Observer here.  `ClickListener` is the Event handler which will call the code block when you click the view .

Comment: that is true, but I need to test this, so I need to go to the view model to add the function and test it with unit test, but thinking about It I could add a callback or an high order function. but that don't apply in all of those cases, but could works .

Comment: I don't understand why you need to involve ViewModel into this during testing . This seems to be cover under Activity test with espresso . You can perform click and validate the intent . There is a espresso library available for intent test I think .